# Where clause using dates - how to add fixed time to a date variable in a conditional argument

Tags: sql, date, db2

I need to calculate which people have a disease_code for asthma in the 12 months before study_date. Study_date is different for each person so I can't use an actual date. I am using a WHERE clause as follows:

```
XXXX (code for main query)
WHERE disease_code = "asthma"
AND (disease_date BETWEEN (study_date - 12 months) AND study_date)
```

How do I code the "study_date - 12 months" part?

Many thanks

Comment: Tag the database vendor for potentially more accurate answers. You don't need the `date` tag. I suppose it's not oracle since you're using a double quote character for stringification.

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL, you must use INTERVAL

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE disease_code = "asthma" 
  AND (disease_date BETWEEN (study_date -  INTERVAL 12 month) AND study_date)
```

in Ibm DB2

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE disease_code = 'asthma' 
  AND (disease_date BETWEEN study_date - 12 MONTHS AND study_date)
```

Comment: And if you do `(study_date -  INTERVAL '12' month)` it will be valid ANSI SQL syntax and supported not only by MySQL, but also several others.

Comment: Brilliant - this has solved the problem! Very grateful for your help with this

Comment: Hi there, I've just realised this is not counting correctly. I used (study_date - 12 month) and it ran but did not count correctly. I get an error message with (study_date - INTERVAL 12 month) and (study_date - INTERVAL '12' month). I am using IBM BD2 which I think is Big SQL. Does anyone know what syntax to use in this type of SQL? Many thanks

Comment: i have added the db2 code

Comment: Great - this has worked! I was using too many brackets. Do you know what SQL syntax this is? Can't seem to work it out from DB2 literature or via the database itself. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: do you get an error? the where clause works in in Idm db2 , maybe you can make a https://dbfiddle.uk/6pjm1B_y  with some sample data or testing